# UWP ListView ScrollViewer - Reset Zoom (Factor)

Tags: listview, scrollview, uwp-xaml, bitmapimage

My ListView holds BitmapImages and I want to allow zooming into these Images.

If I go **ScrollViewer.** ...I don't get the zomming factors.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="SimplePdfViewer.SimplePdfViewerControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SimplePdfViewer"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Unloaded="root_Unloaded"
x:Name="root">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemEdit">
        <!-- spacing between pages-->
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 3"/>
        <!-- Setting Background Color of PDf Placeholders to White-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                PlaceholderBackground="White"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="PdfListView"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind DocumentDataSource}"
              ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled" 
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemEdit}"
              SelectionMode="None">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- Implement Dynamic Width! -> Added for Placeholder Width -->
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="BitmapImage">
                <ListViewItem 
                    Height="1180"
                    Width="800"
                    Background="White"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False">
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind}"/>
                </ListViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to reset the zoomed-in image to the original size?

thanks for the help cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and as @user1419778's answer, you should find the [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer) object from the ListView, then you can use the [ScrollViewer.ChangeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.changeview) Method's `zoomFactor` parameter  to reset its [ZoomFactor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.zoomfactor#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_ZoomFactor).

Firstly, you can find the [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer) object from the ListView using the following method in a helper class.

```
public static class UIHelper
{
    public static ChildElement FindVisualChild<ChildElement>(this DependencyObject obj)
        where ChildElement : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is ChildElement)
                return (ChildElement)child;
            else
            {
                ChildElement childOfChild = FindVisualChild<ChildElement>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer) object and reset its [ZoomFactor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.zoomfactor#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_ZoomFactor) in your UserControl's code behind.

```
private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer=PdfListView.FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>();
    //change view to vertical offset and set the zoom factor to 1.
    //The default zoom factor is 1.0, where 1.0 indicates no additional scaling
    scrollViewer.ChangeView(0, scrollViewer.VerticalOffset, 1.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get a handle from your scroll viewer you can use `ScrollViewer.ChangeView()` to set how zoomed in your image is.